# Не получается подсветить активный пункт меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не могу подсветить выбранное меню. Вот мой код:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('current-menu-item');
});
```

```css
#nav > li span {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#nav > li:hover,
#nav > li.current-menu-item,
#nav > li.current_page_item {
  background: url(/wp-content/themes/new/img/current-menu-item.png) no-repeat 0px -37px;
}
#nav > li:hover span,
#nav > li.current-menu-item span,
#nav > li.current_page_item span {
  display: block;
  background: url(/wp-content/themes/new/img/current-menu-item.png) no-repeat top right;
}
#nav > li:hover a,
#nav > li.current-menu-item a,
#nav > li.current_page_item a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
  <li><a href="/"><span>Главная</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="best-story"><span>Проекты</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about"><span>О нас</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="share-story"><span>Контакты </span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Помогите найти ошибку, спасибо!

Comment: Ваше меню дублируется на каждой странице, куда ведут линки или вы подставляете шаблон? Или по ссылке вы вставляете кусок в этот же документ? Помогите немного помочь Вам!

Comment: выборка ищет по классу, а присвоен ИД

Answer (score 0):

В задании `HTML`, `CSS` и `jQuery` не соответствуют друг другу:
1. jQuery ищет по классу `.nav`, а должен искать по айди `#nav`
2. jQuery добавляет класс элементу `a`, а стили прописаны для `li`

Исправить можно, например, так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').parent().addClass('current-menu-item');
});
```